# Mongoose connected doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I don't know why buy when I do a mongoose connect nothing happens...

This is my code:

```
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

require('./routes/routes.js')(app); //load routes

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Prueba', function(err) {
    if (err){
        console.log("DB NOT CONNECTED ERROR: " + err);
    }else{
        console.log("DB NOT CONNECTED");
    }        
});
```

So I have another example project with the same connect protocol and in that project all works fine but in my project nothing happens...

Thank you

(SOLVED) solved upgrading from `"mongoose": "^3.8.40"` to `"mongoose": "^4.13.4"`;. Thanks to @Grégory NEUT.

Comment: I think that it do try to connect and don't succeed. Because of the timeout is high it look like nothing is happening. You should look at how to change the delay before the connection fail, then you i'll have an error to display.

Comment: Thank you I set the timeoutMS and now I can see the error.